# Weird "illegal start of expression" error in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

In the following programs, `command` is a byte array field in `Apdu` class. The problem is that my IDE (Netbeans) mark the line of

```
apdu.command = {(byte) 0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
```

As error, with the message *illegal start of expression*, while it is okay to use the following instead:

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
apdu.command = bytes;
```

What's wrong with the first programs?

---

First program:
[image]

Second Program:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array variable with :

```
apdu.command = new byte[] {(byte) 0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
```

The initialization you tried is only valid in array declaration expressions.

Answer (score 1):

array syntax `{}` can only be used for initialization not for assignment.

you need to use `apdu.command =new byte[] {(byte) 0x00, (byte)0xa4, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};`.